# table relationships in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, relationship

I am trying to document tables in a specific schema and their relationships in snowflake. I have run queries from information_schema.tables and .columns but it doesn't appear to tell me the child/parent relationships with the tables.

Comment: Is there any way you could [edit] your question to share a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem?  You're less likely to get help if we don't know what you tried that is not working.  See: [ask].

Comment: I figured this out, snowflake as I recently learned does not have foreign keys, so table relationships are not presented in snowflake. I searched information_schema table for '%ID%' FIELDS and manually diagramed the relationships.

Comment: Glad you found the answer.  If you want, you might [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) to let others know the resolution.